# error in synthesizing variable and implementing method

Tags: iphone

I'm getting error when synthesizing variable '@synthesize property must be in implementation context' and for method 'Method definition not in @implementation context'
how should i resolve it?
Thank you

Comment: Hey got it,actually i deleted @implementation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your class **method** and `@synthesize` variable between 
 `@implementation` and `@end` in your **.m** (implementation) file .

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myVar1,myVar2,myVar3;

-(void) method1:(id) myVariable
{

}

-(void) method2
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

From error description I guess you've put @synthesize directive outside of class implementation, i.e. make sure that it goes after @implementation in you file:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myVar;
```